# How to apply different filters to each page in Spotfire Web Player?

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to figure out how to apply different filtering schemas for each page in an Analysis file in Spotfire Web Player/Consumer.

I have found that the Spotfire Analyst supports that (see image below) and I can create different Filtering schemas and apply them for each page:
[image]
However, the Spotfire Web Player does not seem to have such an option. I have checked the JavaScript API ([link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire_Web_Player_JavaScript_API_Reference/html/T_spotfire_webPlayer_Customization.htm)) but I cannot seem to find if there is such an option supported in the web player. Could anyone please share their experience if you know how that can be achieved

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the desired filters in a text area? Is there a reason the user has to use the filter panel?

In a text area filter you can specify your filtering scheme. Note I'm in 7.13 not X.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I haven't tried putting the filters in a text area (I am not sure what you mean by that - I am new to the Spotfire Framework, could you be more specific). As for the reason why I need the filter panel, I would like to enable our users so they can switch filtering schemas on each page in the analysis file (in the Web Player).

Comment: When the user is on a specific page will there be a reason to change filtering schemes while on that page?  
Because filters duplicate the tables in memory consider using limiting data by marking instead. Have you heard of this?

Comment: My client wants to have a defined set of filtering schemas on a specific page (ideally be able to create filtering schemas but that is not possible on the Web Player from what I've found). I have not heard of limiting data by marking, unfortunately.